# My try catch does not show a warning message

Tags: java, exception, applet, dialog

I am making an applet and I made a try catch block that when the program is getting the text from three of the textfields, if any of the textfield is not an integer it should show a dialogue box saying invalid input, however, nothing shows up and I'm not sure how to add a dialogue box onto my applet

```
try{
        if (e.getSource() == bttn)
        {

            as=T1.getText();
            ag=T2.getText();
            ab=T3.getText();
            as=as.trim();
            ag=ag.trim();
            ab=ab.trim();

            redColor= Integer.parseInt(as);
            greenColor= Integer.parseInt(ag);
            blueColor= Integer.parseInt(ab);
        }
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException exception){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Input","TITLE",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably here :

```
if (e.getSource() == bttn)
```

This condition is probably never true.

change it to

```
if (e.getSource().equals(bttn))
```

Oh, and `parseInt` throws `NumberFormatException`, not `InputMismatchException`.

Comment: I loveee you, finally it works I've been trying to do this since yesterday, thank you very much